# Python subprocess not able to find `gh` CLI on GHA runner

Tags: python, github, subprocess, github-actions

I am creating a GitHub Action to allow maintainers tag PRs if they have an open and valid issue tagged to them. To make this possible, I earlier relied upon scripting, but now I wish to switch to the GH CLI. I wrote the Python script to avail the PR body via `subprocess` but run into this error on GitHub Actions runner:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/main.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/main.py", line 19, in main
    body = subprocess.check_output(["gh", "pr", "view", url])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line [80](https://github.com/HarshCasper/***/runs/7409120915?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:82)0, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gh': 'gh'
```

The code looks something like this:

```py
url = os.getenv("INPUT_PRURL")
body = subprocess.check_output(["gh", "pr", "view", url])
```

My workflow step is:

```bash
- name: Issue Validator
  uses: ./.github/actions/
  id: validator
  env:
    GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  with:
    prurl: ${{ github.event.pull_request.url }}
```

I would like to get some help to understand why a Python subprocess is not able to identify the GH CLI. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what runner are you using?

Comment: I am using an Ubuntu runner

Comment: can you please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?